# Error deserializing wallpaper image : iPad

Tags: ipad

What does the following error indicates

> 5/19/11 8:06:45 PM SpringBoard[9712] Error deserializing
>   wallpaper image: Error
>   Domain=CPBitmapErrorDomain Code=0 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (CPBitmapErrorDomain error 0 - No data
>   provided to
>   CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData)"
>   UserInfo=0x70b9c80 {NSDescription=No
>   data provided to
>   CPBitmapCreateImagesFromData}

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you read the error message, it is telling you that a wallpaper was unable to be deserialised because no data was provided to the function named CPBitMapCreateImagesFromData. Pretty self explanitory.

Other than that, it sounds like you're either working on a jailbroken phone or trying to do things that aren't supported by the official iOS SDK - in which case my help ends here.

Or you're a user who is trying to understand why an image they set as a wallpaper isn't displaying and found their way to the iPad's console - in which case, this isn't the place to be asking.

Comment: how to find wats wrong in my code?Some times i get bad excess error with this above error.Some times app works fine some time doesnt.I m not using jailbreak.I m running app through Xcode.

Comment: There is no official API for working with Wallpapers on iPad. I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also, I **think** it's because most of the tutorials are written with an iphone in mind and I was using an iPad.  I was working with an ipad and when following these tutorials i was getting this problem.

When you are creating the project I choose View based application.  In the same wizard there's a combo box for 'iPhone' and 'iPad'..  If I leave that as iPhone then my application doesnt start in the simulator and I see the error you mention.  If I set that to iPad then everything works fine.

I dont understand why that should make a difference tbh..

Comment: Actually, i still get the message about wallpaper, it just doesnt seem to matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but only when I was not debugging, what happened was that in the dealloc function [super dealloc] was called at the top of the function rather than at the end.  The "deserializing wallpaper" message is probably due to some sort of memory corruption that occurred since I had code after [super dealloc] trying to use pointers that were now garbage. I had NSZombie activated but it had no effect. Why this only crashed when I was not hooked up to the debugger is beyond me at the moment.

Thankfully this bug was fixed after a few diffs in source control, but initially I was pretty perplexed at the message and the fact that it was a bug where the debugger couldn't be used only induced more panic.

I'm sure you've long fixed your problem but I thought it'd be helpful to put this out there for others.